# Restrict access with htaccess but allow from web pages

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, post, restriction

How can I restrict access with a .htaccess file `Deny from all` but all $.post requests, $.get request, etc. How could I still access the file from a page but revoke direct access by just going to it in a browser?

Comment: So you only want to allow POST requests and not GET?

Comment: `if (empty($_POST) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 403 Forbidden"); exit; }`?

Comment: allow only AJAX requests to a page? and forbid accessing from browser?

Comment: @MikeBrant No allow both, but stop users from going to the file (php) in their browser. (e.g. http://website.com/restricted/file.php). I'll clarify.

Comment: are the `$.post` and `$.get` , jQuery AJAX ?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix I know, hopefully I'm being clear here... I want to be able to use the pages, but keep people from navigating to it, if that makes sense.

Comment: in that case you need to detected IF its an AJAX request by finding the `X-Requested-With` in headers, IF its not then user tries to browse to the page via a browser.

Comment: @Pete You are of course aware that there is absolutely no 100% spoof-proof way to do this? It just simply isn't possible to do it in a way that even a fairly novice hacker can circumvent.

Comment: Yes per @GeoPhoenix comments I would inject a header that you could then control access based on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable browser access using HTACCESS by mod_rewrite and conditions like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Firefox/4.*$
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L,NS]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php?e=404
```

To access the page you can use cURL with options like

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "allowed_agent");
```